# How to create a multicolumn GiST index in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql, tsvector

The postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) specifies that a GiST index can have multiple columns, but does not provide an example of what this might look like.

I have a table that tracks assets owned by different customers.

```
CREATE TABLE asset (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    description text NOT NULL,
    customer_id uuid NOT NULL
);
```

I'm writing a query that allows a customer to search for an asset based on words in it's description.

```
SELECT *
FROM asset
WHERE to_tsvector('english', asset.description) @@ plainto_tsvector('english', ?)
AND asset.customer_id = ?;
```

Were this a non-tsvector query, I'd build a simple multicolumn index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON asset(customer_id, description);
```

I can create an index *only* on the tsvector:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON asset USING gist(to_tsvector('english', asset.description));
```

However, the query optimizer doesn't use the gist index, because it seems to want to do `customer_id` filtering first. Is there a way that I can include the non-tsvector field `customer_id` in the gist index, somehow, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Hi @andrew-rueckert, long time has passed, can you pleas provide solution you've used?

Comment: I belive that btree_gin extension can help, but can't find any info on it

Comment: @BogdanMart unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem. My index is only on the description field, and I found that this gave me _good enough_ performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a multi column GIN or GiST index in Postrgres using the following:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name 
USING gist (field_one gist_trgm_ops, field_two gist_trgm_ops);
```